# Additional key: values not being added to Python Dictionary

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary

**Summary problem:** Building an API endpoint and trying to push new key:values to the existing API. Not knowing if I am correctly adding key value pairs or not. Familiar with Ruby but first time Python user!

**Context**:
I currently have a method that will format given information into a Python Dictionary to be used as a JSON for my API. I have one method that pushes information to this method but another that is not functioning. Can anybody spot why?

**Things I've tried:**
Feature test using command line environment
Getting visibility - Printing

**Environment**:
MacOS 11.1, python 3.9.1, VSCode

Code:

**METHOD THAT IS FORMATTING**

```
class Database(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.data = {}

def insert_entity(self, kind, entity):
    kind_dict = self.data.get(kind, {})
    entity_id = entity.get('id', str(uuid4()))
    if not isinstance(entity_id, str):
        raise Exception('Entity `id` must be a string')
    entity['id'] = entity_id
    kind_dict[entity_id] = entity
    self.data[kind] = kind_dict
    return entity

def get_entity(self, kind, entity_id):
    entities = self.data.get(kind, {})
    return entities.get(entity_id, None)

def get_all_entities(self, kind):
    return list(self.data.get(kind, {}).values())
```

**METHOD THAT IS WORKING:**

```
def initialise_user_data():
first_names = ['Ron', 'Paul', 'Simon', 'David', 'Phil', 'Ada', 'Julia']
last_names = [
    'Legend', 'Mac', 'Stuartson', 'Sili', 'Word', 'Nine',
    'Smith'
]
for index in range(len(first_names)):
    first_name = first_names[index]
    last_name = last_names[index]
    email = str(random.randint(0, 9999)) + "@email.com"
    user_data = {
        'firstName': first_name,
        'lastName': last_name,
        'email': email
    }
    database.insert_entity('User', user_data)
```

**METHOD THAT IS NOT WORKING:**

```
def initialise_event_data():
users = database.get_all_entities('User')
for user in users:
    for _ in range(random.randint(0, 10)):
        database.insert_entity(
            'Event', {
                'userId': user['id'],
                'points': 100,
                'eventName': 'levels_completed'
            })
```

ALL METHODS ARE INVOKED AS SUCH:

```
database = InMemoryDatabase()
initialise_data()

def initialise_data():
initialise_user_data()
initialise_event_data()
initialise_follow_data()
```

Comment: what is the state of database you expect? how does it differ from what you get? you are stating that method is not working but you dnot ewen tell us what it should do

Comment: Hi Jakub, 

I am expecting the additional data points ('Event') to be added to each user. Something like: 

[{'firstName': 'Ron', 
'lastName': 'Legend', 
'email': '8548@email.com', 
'id': '502b5f80-d221-47cb-acf3-f44a89c640c9', 
'Event':{
'userId: '502b5f80-d221-47cb-acf3-f44a89c640c9', 
'points': 100, 
'eventName': 'lesson_completed'}
}]

Comment: well the fact that you are inserting random amount of Events may be the issue, i tried your code and it have performed as expected

Comment: Did you you receive roughly what I put in the comment above? If so, how did you invoke in order to get the filled Json? Thanks in advance Jakub!

Comment: well i just copied your code and printed out the Database.data, as expected there were 7 users and random amount of of events linked to users if you vant to store database in json then search for `how to serilize dict to json`

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help Jakub